# Can't set up https access on apache 2 (ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)

Tags: ssl, https

I've already looked at a number of how to guides and other posts on server fault but nothing seems to work and in Firefox I always get that same error (ssl_error_rx_record_too_long). I purchased an ssl cert from GoDaddy and installed all of the files to my Debian server at /etc/apache2/ssl. Here is what my /etc/apache2/ports.conf looks like (comments removed):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    NameVirtualHost *:443
    Listen 443 ssl
</IfModule>
```

And here is what my /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName www.cayugaserver.info
    ServerAlias cayugaserver.info
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/a23a14d4f3b5b1bd.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cayugaserver.info.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName www.cayugaserver.info
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I've already checked and the module ssl has been loaded through sudo a2enmod ssl and the site default-ssl has been enabled with sudo a2ensite default-ssl. Also the site works completely fine unencrypted. My best guess is that I am somehow using the wrong files for encryption but I'm still not really sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SSL virtual host is misconfigured.

Try using the `SSLCertificateChainFile` instead of `SSLCACertificateFile` - the bundle you've downloaded should be used as an *intermediate* certificate, not a *certificate authority*.

You should only need to use the `SSLCACertificateFile` option when your OS doesn't have the root or CA certificate locally - most often never the case for up-to-date certificates that use a well-regarded public CA.